# viber. Ошибка: "Действие не может быть выполнено."

Tags: javascript, php, html, viber

При переходе на ссылку по вайберу, открывается само приложение и выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописывал ссылку для viber в виде с кодировкой для URL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в виде с плюсом (без кодировки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в виде без плюса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, почему ни на мобильном, не на телефоне не работает?

Все подобные соц. сети открываются без проблем.
Пример ссылок брал с [этого](http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/kak-sdelat-ssylki-na-viber-whatsapp-telegram.html) сайта и [этого](https://smartlanding.biz/ssylka-na-whatsapp-telegram-viber.html).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный вариант

```
viber://chat?number=%2B<номер в международном формате, без знака +>
```

Comment: этот вариант предназначен для ПК, его тоже пробовал и аналогичная ситуация.

Comment: Нет, он работает на всех устройствах